# Classifying dates based on a range

Tags: r

I written a function that classify certain dates as seasons. I have the following variables:

```
x <- "2014-03-03"
x <- as.Date(x, format = "%Y-%m-%d")


start2014
[1] "2014-09-01"

start2015
[1] "2015-09-01"
```

But when I try this function:

```
ifelse((x > start2014 && x < start2015), 1, 0)
```

I still get:

```
[1] 0
```

While it should evaluate to [1]

Any thoughts why this goes wrong?

Comment: 2014-03-03 is not between 2014-09-01 and 2015-09-01..

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, `2014-03-03` is not greater `2014-09-01`:

```
x <- c("2014-03-03", "2014-12-01")
x <- as.Date(x, format = "%Y-%m-%d")

start2014 <- as.Date("2014-09-01")
start2015 <- as.Date("2015-09-01")

ifelse((x > start2014 & x < start2015), 1, 0)
[1] 0 1
```